# MySQL Is there any way. How can speed up the query

Tags: mysql, performance

I have made a query that gives me the results I need but is very very slow.

DB : Mysql

The problem: very slow.

The question: Is there any way I can speed up the query!

Thanks in advance!

```
SELECT  Count(*) AS totalCount
    FROM  
      ( SELECT  Max(issue_cnt) AS max_count, deal_id, issue_date, penalty_point,
                sale_volume, penalty_classify_code
            FROM  
              ( SELECT  penalty.deal_id, Count(*) AS issue_cnt,
                        Max(penalty_point) AS max_point,
                        penalty.issue_date, penalty.penalty_point,
                        penalty.sale_volume,
                        penalty.penalty_classify_code
                    FROM  bizinfo.tb_pc_sale_penalty penalty, 
                      ( SELECT  Max(penalty_point) AS max_point,
                                penalty.deal_id, penalty.issue_date,
                                penalty.sale_volume,
                                penalty.penalty_classify_code
                            FROM  bizinfo.tb_pc_sale_penalty penalty,
                                  bizinfo.tb_deal_info deal
                            WHERE  penalty.deal_id = deal.deal_id
                              AND  penalty.issue_date >= '2016-01-01'
                              AND  penalty.issue_date < '2016-03-16'
                              AND  Date_format(penalty.registe_date, '%Y-%m-%d') <=
                                   Date_format(Now(), '%Y-%m-%d')
                            GROUP BY  deal_id , issue_date
                      ) terms
                    WHERE  penalty.deal_id = terms.deal_id
                      AND  penalty.issue_date = terms.issue_date
                      AND  penalty.sale_volume = terms.sale_volume
                      AND  penalty.penalty_point = terms.max_point
                      AND  penalty.issue_date >= '2016-01-01'
                      AND  penalty.issue_date < '2016-03-16'
                      AND  Date_format(penalty.registe_date, '%Y-%m-%d') <=
                           Date_format(Now(), '%Y-%m-%d' )
                    GROUP BY  deal_id , penalty.sale_volume , issue_date ,
                              penalty.penalty_classify_code
              ) choice
            GROUP BY  deal_id , issue_date
      ) selection
    left join  
      ( SELECT  1 AS cnt, penalty_classify_code, penalty_point,
                process_condition,
                deal_id, issue_date, registe_date, company_id
            FROM  bizinfo.tb_pc_penalty_point_finalize
            WHERE  issue_date >= '2016-01-01'
              AND  issue_date < '2016-03-16'
      ) finalize ON selection.deal_id = finalize.deal_id
      AND  selection.issue_date = finalize.issue_date
    left join  
      ( SELECT  Ifnull(SUM(penalty_point), 0) AS point, company_id
            FROM  bizinfo.tb_pc_penalty_point_finalize
            WHERE  process_condition = 1
              AND  penalty_point > 0
              AND  registe_date >= Date_sub(Curdate(), interval 89 day)
              AND  registe_date < Date_format(Now(), '%Y-%m-%d')
            GROUP BY  company_id
      ) cumulate ON finalize.company_id = cumulate.company_id
    left join  
      ( SELECT  Count(*) AS cnt, penalty.deal_id, penalty.issue_date
            FROM  bizinfo.tb_pc_sale_penalty penalty, bizinfo.tb_deal_info deal
            WHERE  deal.deal_id = penalty.deal_id
              AND  penalty.issue_date >= '2016-01-01'
              AND  penalty.issue_date < '2016-03-16'
              AND  penalty_point < 0
            GROUP BY  deal_id , issue_date
      ) suspension ON selection.deal_id = suspension.deal_id
      AND  selection.issue_date = suspension.issue_date
    left join  
      ( SELECT  penalty.deal_id, penalty.issue_date, Count(*) AS all_issue_count,
                Ifnull(exp.explain_cnt, 0) AS explain_count,
                SUM(penalty.penalty_point) AS penalty_cumulative_point,
                penalty_point AS penalty_allocate_point, deal.company_id,
                deal.md_id, deal.team_id, deal.main_name
            FROM  
              ( SELECT  deal_id,
                        CASE WHEN penalty_point > 0
                             THEN penalty_point
                             ELSE 0 END AS penalty_point,
                        issue_date
                    FROM  bizinfo.tb_pc_sale_penalty
              ) penalty
            left join  
              ( SELECT  1 AS explain_cnt, exp.deal_id, exp.issue_date
                    FROM  bizinfo.tb_pc_penalty_explain exp
                    GROUP BY  exp.deal_id , exp.issue_date
              ) exp ON exp.deal_id = penalty.deal_id
              AND  exp.issue_date = penalty.issue_date, bizinfo.tb_deal_info deal
            WHERE  penalty.deal_id = deal.deal_id
            GROUP BY  penalty.deal_id , penalty.issue_date , deal.company_id
      ) alltype ON selection.deal_id = alltype.deal_id
      AND  selection.issue_date = alltype.issue_date, bizinfo.tb_deal_info deal,
        bizinfo.tb_partner_member member, bizinfo.tb_partner_member member2,
        bizinfo.tb_pc_communication_master_code master,
        bizinfo.tb_company_info company
    WHERE  selection.deal_id = deal.deal_id
      AND  deal.md_id = member.user_id
      AND  deal.team_id = member2.user_seq
      AND  master.group_cd = 'P10080'
      AND  master.value_cd NOT IN ('p99')
      AND  master.value_cd = selection.penalty_classify_code
      AND  alltype.company_id = company.company_id;
```

Comment: You would have to analyze the query and possibly add indexes.

Comment: Analyze it. Possibly reduce subqueries. Give information about the tables, row counts, plans... One can't analyze SQL by itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `FROM a JOIN b ON ...` syntax instead of `FROM a,b WHERE ...`.

`FROM ( SELECT ... ) JOIN ( SELECT ... ) ON ...` (or the older format) optimizes poorly.  Try to avoid it.

`Date_format(Now(), '%Y-%m-%d')` --> `CURRENT_DATE()`.

This is simpler and more optimizable; I suspect it gives the same 'intent':

```
Date_format(penalty.registe_date, '%Y-%m-%d') <=
Date_format(Now(), '%Y-%m-%d' )
-->
penalty.registe_date < NOW()
```

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` so we can judge the utility of the indexes and understand the datatypes.  (Example: is issue_date a `DATE` or a `DATETIME`?)  Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT` so we can see how the query is *currently* being performed.

Consider whether `JOIN` is appropriate instead of `LEFT JOIN`.

What version of MySQL are you running?

`penalty` might benefit from `INDEX(deal_id, issue_date, sale_volume, penalty_point, registe_date)` -- specifically with `registe_date` last.

In one of the early subqueries, why is `deal` included?  (`... FROM  bizinfo.tb_pc_sale_penalty penalty, bizinfo.tb_deal_info deal ...`)  Without `deal`, `INDEX(deal_id, issue_date)` would be a very good index.  I'm not sure what to recommend if you include `deal`.

`tb_pc_penalty_point_finalize` needs `INDEX(issue_date)`.

`left join  ( SELECT  Ifnull(SUM(penalty_point), 0) AS point ...` can be removed totally!  It is extra work, but you don't use the `point` it generates.  And, since it is `LEFT`, nobody cares if the `SELECT` finds anything.  Perhaps other `LEFT JOINs` are also useless?

`master` probably needs `INDEX(group_cd)`; `selection` probably needs `INDEX(penalty_classify_code)`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes , you can apply indexes to the columns that are used in **WHERE** clause
Like add indexes on selection.deal_id  , deal.deal_id  , deal.md_id and member.user_id.
But its Not good to have too many indexes on a table.

As a general rule, you should have indexes on all primary keys (you don't have a choice in that), all foreign keys, and any other fields you commonly use to fetch rows.

Answer (score 1):

Create INDEX on the columns involved in your query.

```
FLUSH TABLES

RESET QUERY CACHE
```

above will free up some memory space.
Good Luck

Comment: Neither of those free up memory space.  Each will empty out a cache without making the freed space available for anything different.  And most subsequent actions will be _slowed down_ until the cache is suitable refilled.